# Report Data Disappears on Postback

Tags: reporting-services, postback, reportviewer

I currently have a reporting services project that is displayed as part of an ASP.NET application.  I have one report that has 2 datetime parameters.  When I type in the textbox some sort of date, nothing appears to happen, but if I click on the little calendar icon and select a date, the page will then post back, and the data that used to show is now gone.  Is there a way to prevent this?  After I hit the "View Report" button, it runs the report with the new parameter, but my users are a bit skittish and if the report disappears on them, they will call the helpline in a full-blown panic.

Help save a developer from irate and panicked users?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post a snippet from the .aspx and .cs/.vb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've set EnabledViewState=true in the calendar and textbox.

Comment: I've enabled ViewState on the ReportViewer.  The parameters are dynamically generated based on the report a user selects.

Comment: Do you know all the possible form elements before? The way we handled in one project was to disable/mark hidden form elements that weren't applicable. And the view state has to be enabled on the elements as well.